# Internet on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Running Very Slowly

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

We have installed a new Terminal Server running windows 2008 r2 enterprise OS, we have a watchguard which authenticates users on a SSO agent &* when the users try to go to a website and scroll down the page the website draws ever so slowly, We have tried to update the graphics card but the server is still very slow,

Is there anything else that we could do to try & resolve this issue? Any ideas would be really be appreciated

Server Specs are Below

---

Operating System: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise 64-bit (6.1, Build 7601) Service Pack 1 (7601.win7sp1_gdr.110622-1506)
           Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
System Manufacturer: HP
       System Model: ProLiant DL380 G6
               BIOS: Default System BIOS
          Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5550  @ 2.67GHz (16 CPUs), ~2.7GHz
             Memory: 24576MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 24566MB RAM
          Page File: 9328MB used, 39801MB available
        Windows Dir: C:\Windows
    DirectX Version: DirectX 11
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
   User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
 System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
    DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
     DxDiag Version: 6.01.7601.17514 32bit Unicode

Comment: What about updating the network drivers?

Answer (score 0):

What about clients ? Are they Windows 7 ? If so, check out RemoteFX feature from Microsoft: http://blogs.technet.com/b/virtualization/archive/2010/03/18/explaining-microsoft-remotefx.aspx

Also check :

- On client rdp settings, that all feature are activated (100M connection profile),
- Check on server network card speed & duplex (And on the switch that it's same, and full duplex in any case)

Comment: Some clients are using RDP from WinXP & Win7Pro, it disconnects them from time to time saying they've been disconnected & reconnects,

Comment: Also check for RDP settings, to be sure someone didn't set to disconnect inactive users

Comment: netstat -e on the server and client to check for errors

Comment: it only disconnects users who are inactive for over an hour but when they are word processing it kicks them & just normal use does this also,

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

E:\users\Administrator>netstat -e
Interface Statistics

                           Received            Sent

Bytes                    1729316073      1964749163
Unicast packets            41583042        42319467
Non-unicast packets          474774           42552
Discards                      15669           15669
Errors                            0               0
Unknown protocols                 0

Comment: discard is very bad. Looks like a speed/duplex mismatch, or server being in 10M instead of 100 or 1000.

Comment: Where would this be located for me to change?

Comment: Look for broadcom or intel software. Else open network card properties, you will see it in the list of settings. Must match what your network admin set on it's side (the switch). Keep auto on both side if possible

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, Would changing the network card settings & making sure it is auto on the switch would this resolve the slow graphics drawing and improve Internet connection?

Comment: definitely if it's not at least 100M full duplex

Comment: The switch is set as Auto at the moment so i just have to set the Nic Card to Auto also? is this right? Or can i set it as 1000?

Comment: Set it as auto if it's not already. If it's already set to auto, you must check how the negociation worked. On the switch, check that it egociated 100M or 1000M and full duplex.